# Resetting Sharp MX-C311 Printer

Tags: printer

I picked up a Sharp MX-C311 MFP as surplus a while ago and I am trying to get it to clear out and reset so we can use it.  So far I have not been able to find anything on forcing a hard reset on this model in the manuals or on google.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I do not have the current admin password, and the office we bought it from is long gone.

Comment: From the manual "8-39 TROUBLESHOOTING ou forgot the 
administrator password. Was the administrator password 
changed from the factory default 
setting?
Contact your dealer or nearest authorised service 
representative.

Comment: If the default password (admin) does not work, I think you need Sharp service.

Comment: I contacted sharp service and their response was to look for a dealer sticker on the machine, or contact another local dealer if there is no such sticker.  They apparently do not support this model directly. (posted the question here before they responded)